# Overlay specific Element during Ajax request

Tags: html, css

how on earth can I add this overlay effect to an specific element instead of the whole body?

http://jsfiddle.net/uL9habv1/

HTML:

```
<div id="elementToOverlay">          
   <p><strong>Blablabla</p>
</div>

<div class="modal"></div>
```

JS:

```
$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
     ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

CSS:

```
 /* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
   Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
   with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
   speak for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
   our animation centered, and no-repeating */

.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('http://sampsonresume.com/labs/pIkfp.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}

/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

(in this case the #elementToOverlay, right at the top). No matter where i change something it just doesn't work out. Either nothing is overlayed or everything...

Thank you very much and kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the overlay is set to `position:fixed` the position will be always relative to the viewport.

Let's say you want to set up the overlay on the first paragraph, first set the container to `position:relative`.

```
#elementToOverlay {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then move the overlay object into that container.

```
<div id="elementToOverlay">
  <p>...</p>
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

And set it to `position:absolute`.

```
.modal {
  position: absolute;
}
```

It will then show up inside that container.

**[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL9habv1/1/)**

Comment: Perfect, even with an explanation ,thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Moving the modal inside `#elementToOverlay` will probably be impractical, so this solution sizes up and positions the modal dynamically to perfectly cover `#elementToOverlay`

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/uL9habv1/2/

```
ele = $('#elementToOverlay');
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");
        $('.modal').css('left',ele.offset().left)
                   .css('width',ele.outerWidth())
                   .css('top',ele.offset().top)
                   .css('height',ele.outerHeight());
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This one is comprehensible :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to solve this by editing your CSS code. The element is currently positioned fixed above everything else with a height and a width of 100%. This will surely overlay anything, no matter of the current element it is on.